# show.hide html elements by jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm new to Jquery here and I have the following code, it is not working, the div blocks are not working as they supposed to be and i just don't know what's wrong with it.

The page is inside a secure zone which only the login user can see. ".WBDF-listing" is referring to the "{module_webappscustomer,22963,a,}" this special syntax will render webapp id 22963 that published by this customer and contains the .WBDF-listing class, same to the ".Enrolled-listing", it refers to "{module_webappscustomer,24347,a,}"

please help. Many thanks.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
if ($('.WBDF-listing').length < 0) {// if user has no Artist Profile
    $('#Enrollment-Add').hide(); //then hide Enrollment Adding link but show profile add link
    $('#Profile-Add').show();
    } else if ($('.WBDF-listing').length > 0) {// if user has Artist Profile but no Enrollment Listing yet
        if ($('.Enrolled-listing').length < 0) {
            $('#Enrollment-Add').show(); //then show Enrollment Adding link and hide profile add link
            $('#Profile-Add').hide(); 
            }
    } else if ($('.WBDF-listing').length > 0) {// if user has Artist Profile and Enrollment Listing
        if ($('.Enrolled-listing').length > 0) {
            $('#Enrollment-Add').empty(); //then hide both Enrollment Adding link and profile add link
            $('#Profile-Add').empty();
            }
    }
});
</script>


<div id="Profile-Add">
<p>You need to create your Artiste Profile first, then go back this page to enroll WBDF festival events</p>
<p><a href="/users/WBDF-profile-artiste-add" class="btn btn-small btn-primary"><em     class="icon-user"></em> <em class="icon-plus"></em> Create My Artiste Profile</a></p>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<div id="Enrollment-Add" style="display: none;">
<h3>Online Enroll</h3>
<p><a href="/users/WBDF-enroll-add" class="btn btn-small btn-primary"><em class="icon-user"></em> <em class="icon-plus"></em> Enroll Now</a></p>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<div id="Profile-Exist" style="display: none;">
<p>{module_webappscustomer,22963,a,}</p>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<div id="Enrolled-listing">
<p>{module_webappscustomer,24347,a,}</p>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the desired functionality and what errors are you getting?

Comment: I don't see an input with an id of `.WBDF-listing`. Is there code missing?

Comment: the .WBDF-listing is referring to the {module_webappscustomer,22963,a,} this special syntax will render webapp id 22963 that published by this customer and contains the .WBDF-listing class

Answer (score 0):

As per your description,in last else if condition enrollment and profile link should hide. .empty () will clear everything inside that respective div

Comment: this is what i thought, but in fact, it is not emptied, it is still showing.

Comment: I think the problem lies in conditions that you are checking.Same condition is checked twice. so only one else if block will get executed. `else if ($('.WBDF-listing').length > 0)`.Remove last else if condition and process that part logic in above else if condition